# Generate table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: tables

Is it possible to create a table with with a dynamic number of columns that depend on some given width, e.g., `\textwidth`? For example, given a fixed-width table `t` with `size(t) <= 0.5\textwidth` that has three columns and looks as follows,

```
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
G & H & I \\
J & K & L \
```

I am asking if it is possible to translate it dynamically into something like:

```
A & B & C  &  G & H & I \\
D & E & F  &  J & K & L \\
```

Comment: That seems awfully confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eplain` has something that's somewhat similar to what you want.

```
\input eplain

\makecolumns 12/6:
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
It's not quite what you want.
\bye
```

[image]

`memoir` has something similar.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\autorows{c}{6}{l}{
        A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the `memoir` package offers the right tools to solve this issue.