# Discouraging line break in an alignment

Tags: tex-core, line-breaking

In the question [Generate table with dynamic number of columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/generate-table-with-dynamic-number-of-columns) the OP posed a question to which my initial reaction was "No".

However, now I've run into something interesting which, if I'm reading it right, would fit the bill. From the *TeX by topic* by Victor Eijkhout (25.2.3):

> `\noalign{\penalty100}` for discouraging a page break (or line break) in between two rows (columns) of an `\halign` (`\valign`).

So if I understood the above correctly, for `\valign` that would read:

> `\noalign{\penalty100}` for discouraging a line break in between two columns of an `\valign`.

I thought: "That's *exactly* what was asked for", but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: `\penalty1000` only discourages a line break; to inhibit it you have to say `\penalty10000`

Comment: @egreg: typo. Fixed to the question. Doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: If I add some columns to that alignment, I don't get any line break. Please, provide a minimal example.

Comment: @egreg: uh, what do you mean "minimal example"? It *is* a minimal example! If you got it to work, could you add that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @morbusg: I don't follow you. It' obvious that the alignment you show will not have any line break when the `\hsize` is reasonable. But if I typeset *your* alignment after `\hsize=1pt` I don't get any line break, that would instead be present if the inserted penalties were less than 10000.

Comment: @egreg: I don't follow you either! `:-D` I just tried it with `\hsize=1pt`, and I get two lines.

Comment: @morbusg: Please, show *precisely* the complete source, because I get only the indentation and the complete alignment on one line (and the overfull rule).

Comment: @egreg: ... it's right there in the question. Complete source (with your `\hsize=1pt` prepended)

Comment: @morbusg: if I compile with pdftex or tex, I get only one line.

Comment: @egreg: what the f... if *I* compile with pdftex, I get two lines!?! BasicTeX-2010 on OSX.

Comment: @morbusg: please, add the complete log to your question.

Comment: @morbusg: I've seen the log. Where are the two lines? I see only one "Overfull `\hbox`" message; two lines would have issued *two* messages.

Comment: @morbusg: Maybe I've found out what you are trying to say. There are *two* lines, because each row in the `\valign` has *two* columns. But the alignment, as far as the line breaking algorithm is concerned, consists of just one line, precisely four consecutive hboxes (the indentation and the three columns). What did you expect? The penalty shows its effect *between* columns of the `\valign` and you've specified an alignment consisting of three columns each formed by two rows.

Comment: @egreg: By "found out what you are trying to say", are you referring to my actual question, the question I am referring to in my question, or...? Please, to avoid further confusion, can you read through my question *with thought*, and the question I'm referring to in the first sentence so we could avoid wild goose chases. I'd be perfecly happy with "You are misunderstading", or "No, you can't do that" -answers, but then I'd like to know why is Victor using the quoted part from my question as an example.

Comment: @morbusg: You are misunderstanding what `\valign` does.

Answer (score 2):

Just as `\halign` creates an alignment by specifying a *prototype row*, `\valign` creates an alignment by specifying a *prototype column*. Inside a `\valign`, `&` specifies the end of a row in a column, and `\cr` means "end-of-column"; each cell and column is typeset in (internal) vertical mode and the whole alignment is then passed to the paragraph builder (in horizontal mode).

In a `\halign` there's no way to slice off one column once the alignment has been built; with a `\valign` it's impossible to slice off a row.

morbusg example specifies an alignment in which there can be an arbitrary number of rows, each with the template `\hbox{\strut#}`; the alignment entries tell TeX to build a succession of three columns (each one with two rows). Columns are separated from the next by a `\penalty10000` which inhibits a line break after each column (and before the first and after the last one, also).

Comment: though it is in fact possible to slice off a column by painfully `\unhbox`-ing the alignment and going through the various boxes.

Comment: @Bruno: That's true, but certainly not an easy task.

Comment: I know. Trying to recreate `\halign` mostly by hand, I got stuck on `\halign to <dimen>` and `\halign spread <dimen>`. The rest (`\noalign`, `\span`) was mostly ok. One case in which I couldn't manage to unbox properly is alignment displays, such as `$$\halign{...}$$`.

Comment: @Bruno: I believe it's the same problem one is faced when trying to unbox a `tabular`, because of the `\mathon` and `\mathoff` items.